# How to convert dictionary to json in Swift, and delete "optional" in json string

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I want to convert a dictionary to json, dictionary as following:

```
[
      [
        "user_event" : "Optional({\n  \"strokes\" : {\n    \"oldText\" : \"er\",\n    \"selection\" : \"error\",\n    \"candidates\" : \"error|errors|era\",\n    \"context\" : \"error \"\n  }\n})",
        "device_type" : "x86_64",
        "language" : "EN_US"
      ],
      [
        "user_event" : "Optional({\n  \"strokes\" : {\n    \"oldText\" : \"\",\n    \"selection\" : \"messages\",\n    \"candidates\" : \"messages|message|in\",\n    \"context\" : \"error messages \"\n  }\n})",
        "device_type" : "x86_64",
        "language" : "EN_US"
      ]
    ]
```

I'm using following code:

```
let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(object, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
let json = NSString.init(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

But the results string has characters as "Optional(" which will cause the json decoder process fail, how can I exclude these additional characters?

Comment: don try to delete the "Optional(", change your data to not contain optionals, transform them to json and the "Optional(" will be gone.

Comment: Even there is no "Optional", such as:  ["did": 65ca26841b0384067e293562aa40d0b0, "input_mode": tap, "language": EN_US, "device_type": x86_64], ["did": 65ca26841b0384067e293562aa40d0b0, "input_mode": tap, "language": EN_US, "device_type": x86_64]], it will still generate "Optional(" as following: Optional([{"did":"65ca26841b0384067e293562aa40d0b0","input_mode":"tap","language":"EN_US","device_type":"x86_64"},{"did":"65ca26841b0384067e293562aa40d0b0","input_mode":"tap","language":"EN_US","device_type":"x86_64"}]), why?

Comment: I used following code:  if let d = data as NSData! {
                let json = NSString.init(data: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("=== json string: \(json)")
                return String(json)
            }
still not working.